# Please could someone explain what this numpy related code does or mean?

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning

Please what do the following lines of code from the code further down mean:

```
 avg= np.mean(a[np.where(a[:,0]== u[0])][:,1])

bestArm = u[0]

 choice = np.where(arms == np.random.choice(arms))[0][0]

runningMean = np.mean(av[:,1])
```

These lines of  code came from a machine learning reinforcement learning program shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(5)

n= 10
arms= np.random.rand(n)
eps= 0.1 #probability of exploration action


def reward(prob):
    reward = 0
    for i in range(10):
        if random.random() < prob:
            reward += 1
    return reward

#initialize memory array; has 1 row defualted to random action index
av = np.array([np.random.randint(0, (n+ 1)), 0]).reshape(1,2) #av = action-value
#greedy method to select best arm based on memory array
def bestArm(a):
    bestArm = 0 #default to o
    bestMean= 0
    for u in a:
        avg= np.mean(a[np.where(a[:,0]== u[0])][:,1]) # calculate mean reward for each action
        if bestMean < avg:
            bestMean = avg
            bestArm = u[0]
    return bestArm        
        
        
     
        
plt.xlabel('Number of times played')
plt.ylabel('Average Reward')
for i in range(500):
    if random.random() > eps: #greedy exploitation action
        choice= bestArm(av)
        thisAV= np.array([[choice, reward(arms[choice])]])
        av= np.concatenate((av, thisAV), axis= 0)
    else:
        choice = np.where(arms == np.random.choice(arms))[0][0]
        thisAV= np.array([[choice, reward(arms[choice])]]) #choice , rewaard
        av= np.concatenate((av, thisAV), axis = 0) # add to our action value memory array
        
        # calculate the mean reward
        runningMean = np.mean(av[:,1])
        plt.scatter(i, runningMean)
```

Please i will appreciate assistance on this, as i have tried googling to understand those lines of code, but was not totally satisfied with the answers i got. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
avg= np.mean(a[np.where(a[:,0]== u[0])][:,1])
```

From the inside out, `a[:,0]==u[0]` produces an array of True and False values where the first column of `a` equals the value in `u[0]`  `np.where` returns the list of indices where that array contains `True`.  Taking `a[np.where...]` returns only those elements of `a`, and the `[:,1]` returns the second column in that subarray.  So, you're taking the average of the rows in the second column of `a` where the first column of `a` equals `u[0]`.

```
choice = np.where(arms == np.random.choice(arms))[0][0]
```

From the inside out, `np.random.choice(arms)` picks an element at random from the `arms` array.  `arms == np.random.choice(arms)` returns True for those rows of `arms` that match the random choice, and False otherwise.  The `np.where`, again, returns the indices of the rows that were True.  So, this is basically you are returning the [0][0] element from an element of `arms` chosen at random.

```
runningMean = np.mean(av[:,1])
```

This takes the average of the second column of `av`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. But  I don't fully understand your explanation of       avg= np.mean(a[np.where(a[:,0]== u[0])][:,1])